# MVC 5 Controller. Single value from database. Single value to ViewBag

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, view, controller, viewbag

I want to get a single database value into my Controller, set it to a ViewBag, and use that ViewBag in my View.

I have trired for hours but there is no examples to be found. My code looks like this:

Controller:

```
public class IntroResponsesController : Controller
{
        ...
        ViewBag.Question1 = new SelectList(db.Surveys, "SurveyID", "Question1");

        //I HAVE ALSO TRIED SOMETHING LIKE THIS:

        if (db.Surveys.Find("Question1") != null)
        {
            ViewBag.Question1 = db.Surveys.Find("Question1");
        }

}
```

View:

```
    <h4>@ViewBag.Question1</h4>
```

My problem is that I do not have code that is meant to get a single value from database. What I have in the first example is a SelectList that is trying to get a **list** for filling a dropdownlist.
That is not what I want to do!

Is there a substitute for the "new SelectedList" action that can give me what I want?

Notice also that the Controller is **IntroResponseController** and the Question1 is a property from the **Survey** Model.

Comment: Which `Survey` do you want? the first one, the last one, all of them?

Comment: Let's just get the SurveyID = 1 for now

Comment: Something like `var string = db.db.Surveys.Find(s => s.SurveyID == 1).Question1;` (assuming `Question1` is a string)

Comment: That's good. Almost there. But it is telling me that

"Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Delegate' because it is not a delegate type"


I found some things about this error but I do not get it.
Maybe I should turn back and build my solution differently?
Did I build this unnecessarily complicated?

In that case; What is the most practical way to get a set db value into the Controller?

Comment: Sorry, try `var survey = db.Surveys.FirstOrDefault(s => s.SurveyID == 1)` then if `survey` is not null `string question = survey.Question1`

Comment: You, sir. Are a man among men. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered by Stephen Muecke:

Try

```
var survey = db.Surveys.FirstOrDefault(s => s.SurveyID == 1)
```

then

```
if survey is not null 

string question = survey.Question1
```